# optimising a `for` loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const parse_data_db = data => {
  const collection = {};
  for (const key in data) {
    collection[key] = key === 'sample' ? data[key].BOOL : data[key].S
  }
  return collection
}
```

Which I tried to modify in order to avoid the for loop, to:

```
const parse_data_db = data => Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: key === 'sample' ? data[key].BOOL : data[key].S,
}), {});
```

But I got an unknown `...acc`

What am I missing, any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Reduce is just a for loop underneath. It is unlikely to improve performance in any meaningful way, since there is now a function call on each iteration.

Comment: Rest properties (`...acc`) are also an experimental feature and not supported by any environment by default.

Comment: thanks for the replies